# Kannel Gateway smpp

Tags: sms, smpp, kannel

I am new to the Kannel gateway. I installed kannel by referring some vids and docs.
After editing the kannel.conf, opensmppbox.conf, sqlbox.conf, I ran the below line
/usr/local/kannel/sbin/bearerbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf &
but got the error in the attached image.
[image]

This the MySQL connection lines in kannel.conf

#--------------------------------

group = mysql-connection

id = dlr-db

host = localhost

username = kannel

password = **********

Database = kannel

max-connections = 1

Do you guys have any idea what's the issue?.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Its just a typo issue. I accidently used Database  instead of database.
:-(